# What does `2` in `GETRLIMIT(2)` mean/come from?

Tags: bash, man

I know `GETRLIMIT(2)` is used to control maximum system resource consumption.

What does `2` in `GETRLIMIT(2)` mean/come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the section of the manpage that explains the use of `GETRLIMIT`. To read e.g. section 2 of the manpage for the command `foo`, type `man 2 foo`.

From `man man`:

> `man` is the system's manual pager. Each page argument given to man is normally the name of a program, utility or function.  The manual  page  associated
>          with  each  of  these  arguments  is then found and displayed. A section, if provided, will direct man to look only in that section of the manual.  The
>          default action is to search in all of the available sections, following a pre-defined order and to show only the first page found, even if page  exists
>          in several sections.
>
> The table below shows the section numbers of the manual followed by the types of pages they contain.
>
> ```
>    1   Executable programs or shell commands
>    2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
>    3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
>    4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
>    5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
>    6   Games
>    7   Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
>    8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
>    9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
> ```